# How to update values from a table using a NTILE function?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

**Abstract:** I am trying to rank these stocks factors by top quintile and bottom quintile to build a long/short portfolio.

Table:

[image]

Desired result:

[image]

Code used:

```
UPDATE MOMENTUM_Quintile 
SET [2006-12-30] = NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY [2006-12-30] DESC)
FROM MOMENTUM_Quintile
```

Error message:

> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error is clear,reason why you can't do this,has to do with Logical query processing .you can try below

```
 With cte
 as(
 select *, NTILE(5) OVER (order by [2006-12-30] desc) as ntile
from
MOMENTUM_Quintile
)
update cte 
set [2006-12-30]=ntile
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it with n columns instead of just one?

Comment: Can you please post expected result and actual result as new question

Comment: I got it ! Thank you

Comment: This question was tagged sqlserver,not sure about postegres.Sorry

Comment: Clear might be an overstatement

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the function inside a subquery:

```
UPDATE t 
SET [2006-12-30] = [2006-12-30_New]
FROM (  SELECT  [2006-12-30],
                [2006-12-30_New]= NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY [2006-12-30] DESC)
        FROM    MOMENTUM_Quintile
    ) AS t;
```

For what it is worth, having dates as column names is a bit of a code smell. I suspect you need to normalise your data. Also, in doing an update of this nature you are going to lose your original data. So while the above will work, I think you probably need to re-think this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a updatable CTE:

```
with toupdate as (
      select mq.*, NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY [2006-12-30] DESC) as tile
      from MOMENTUM_Quintile mq
     )
update toupdate
    set [2006-12-30] = tile;
```

You can repeat this for multiple columns:

```
with toupdate as (
      select mq.*,
             NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY [2006-12-30] DESC) as tile1,
             NTILE(5) OVER (ORDER BY [2007-01-30] DESC) as tile2
      from MOMENTUM_Quintile mq
     )
update toupdate
    set [2006-12-30] = tile1,
        [2007-01-30] = tile2;
```

Comment: Would you know how to do it with N columns instead of just 2.. like a loop